# Change Vagrant port forwarding on a running system

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I have a Vagrant system up and running and I want to apply a change to it which is as little as changing one of the forwarding rules.

From [this page](http://vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/ports.html):

> Forwarded ports are applied during `vagrant up` like any other
>   configuration. But if you already have a running system, calling
>   `vagrant reload` will apply them without re-importing and re-building
>   everything.
>
> Note that forwarding ports requires a virtual machine restart since
>   VirtualBox won’t pick up on the forwarded ports until it is completely
>   restarted.

Sounds exactly like what I want! But if I try a `vagrant reload` all of my Chef recipes are reloaded and since the full process takes about half an hour, I have to go to the kitchen and grab the nth cup of coffee.

Is there any way to apply Vagrantfile changes on a running system without going trough the whole provisioning process? I cannot drink so much coffee.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Have you tried using the VirtualBox user interface to add the new port forwarding rule manually? Open VirtualBox and select the running VM, then hit *Settings->Network->Port Forwarding* and add the new rule to, for example, forward `127.0.0.1:2223` to `10.0.2.15:22`. After doing this I was able to connect to my VM on ports 2222 (as per usual) and 2223 (the new rule).

Naturally, you would add this new rule to your `Vagrantfile` at the same time to ensure that the mapping becomes permanent after the eventual restart.

Also, if your VM provisioning takes so long, have you considered moving some of the chef/puppet steps into the actual base box? For example, perhaps you are installing a bunch of server software that takes a while to install. Repackaging the box with this software already installed could dramatically reduce your Vagrant startup time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you bro, extremly simple and fast applied solution

Comment: For anyone reading, the next answer by awongh might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Yup, although the VM restart may not be what is wanted. (And that command didn't exist in 2011 when I wrote the above answer!)

Answer (score 21):

you can do

> vagrant reload --no-provision

and it should run without chef, puppet, etc.

although it will still reboot the vm- feels like "But if you have an already running system..." is maybe a bit misleading.

Comment: Restarting the VM is the problem though even if a bit faster