# Adding port forwarding on an existing vagrant box

Tags: vagrant

My running vagrant box (ubuntu, on a OS X Mavericks host) has been running fine.

I am trying to set up pgAdmin from the host, and am having trouble opening a new port for the sql traffic.

I added a line to my Vagrantfile (the last one):

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 8080   # http
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 35729, host: 35729
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 7001   # postgres
```

I ran **vagrant provision** and bounced the Vagrant box several times. When it reboots the new port forwarding is not listed:

```
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 3000 => 8080 (adapter 1)
    default: 35729 => 35729 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
```

Curl gives a negative response also:

```
➜  ~  curl -v 'http://localhost:7001/'
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fde1a004400
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fde1a004400) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 7001 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
*   Trying fe80::1...
* Failed connect to localhost:7001; Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:7001; Connection refused
```

Related posts:

[Vagrant Port Forwarding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042330/vagrant-port-forwarding-not-working)

[Cannot connect to Postgres running on VM from host machine using MD5 method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139017/cannot-connect-to-postgres-running-on-vm-from-host-machine-using-md5-method)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since the 5432<-->7001 port mapping is not listed in the Vagrant up sequence, it's not happening.

I would try a `vagrant reload` which is supposed to reload those part of the Vagrantfile again.

If that doesn't work, you could also try manually adding the port mapping, at least to confirm the connection to your application. The accepted answer for [Change Vagrant port forwarding on a running system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565446/change-vagrant-port-forwarding-on-a-running-system) explains how to do that in the VirtualBox UI.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I did try the reload option but no go. I wanted to avoid making changes outside the vagrantfile if possible. If I can't come up with anything else I will try it.

Answer (score 28):

Another way to set up a temporary terminal, besides opening up the VirtualBox settings, is to use `vagrant ssh`, with additional arguments given after the `--`:

```
vagrant ssh -- -L 3000:localhost:3000
```

This will forward port 3000 on the host to port 3000 on the guest.

The first number is for the host. To forward port 7001 on the host to the default postgresql port on the guest:

```
vagrant ssh -- -L 7001:localhost:5432
```

This will only last as long as your ssh session. If ssh gets disconnected, run it again. To make it persist after restarts, add it to your `Vagrantfile`.

Comment: One of the best answers I have seen. Saved a lot of time. Thanks a lot

Comment: Brilliant answer. For those who use `vscode`, just make sure to forward your ssh request your port host to port 22, for example,  vagrant ssh -- -L 3000:localhost:22. And then you can configure your `vscode` to use `localhost` port 3000 to set things up.